# How can I get a European visa if I was refused a Japanese visa

Tags: europe, japan, visa-refusals, sri-lankan-citizens

I'm from Sri Lanka. Recently I applied for a Japanese temporary visitor visa. It was refused. Will this have any impact on my European student visa?

Comment: Do you have a student visa already or are you asking about what will happen if you apply for one?  Did Japan stamp a refusal notice in your passport or simply send a note about the refusal?

Comment: Yes, your thoughts may right. But I got refusals from Japan embassy twice

Answer (score 1):

- If the Japanese visa had been granted, that would have been positive. So the **decision** that it has been refused will have a small negative impact.
- The **reasons** why the Japanese visa was refused will probably have a significant impact. Most industrialized countries look for similar things, like a reassurance that the visitor will leave again.